# How does one use php to determine what season it is in php and then utilise a php style sheet according to that season

Tags: php, wordpress

I NEED YOUR HELP PLEASE!
I have a client that wants to change the background color of all h1 h2 h3s and certain sections' background color according to the season that they are in, but for the life of me I just can't and PHP is my weakest point. Is there anyone here that would be able to give me advice on this and how I would implement it on a WordPress website? I did find the following code snippet online but i would need to modify this so that it selects a specific style sheet, and then how do i setup the style sheet to be php and get it start styling...
Much love to all!

````
function current_season() {
       // Locate the icons
       $icons = array(
               "spring" => "images/spring.png",
               "summer" => "images/summer.png",
               "autumn" => "images/autumn.png",
               "winter" => "images/winter.png"
       );

       // What is today's date - number
       $day = date("z");

       //  Days of spring
       $spring_starts = date("z", strtotime("March 21"));
       $spring_ends   = date("z", strtotime("June 20"));

       //  Days of summer
       $summer_starts = date("z", strtotime("June 21"));
       $summer_ends   = date("z", strtotime("September 22"));

       //  Days of autumn
       $autumn_starts = date("z", strtotime("September 23"));
       $autumn_ends   = date("z", strtotime("December 20"));

       //  If $day is between the days of spring, summer, autumn, and winter
       if( $day >= $spring_starts && $day <= $spring_ends ) :
               $season = "spring";
       elseif( $day >= $summer_starts && $day <= $summer_ends ) :
               $season = "summer";
       elseif( $day >= $autumn_starts && $day <= $autumn_ends ) :
               $season = "autumn";
       else :
               $season = "winter";
       endif;

       $image_path = $icons[$season];

       echo $image_path;
}

?>```
````

Comment: One of the most important skills in programming is **breaking the problem down**. Write a function that returns the current season as a string; give it a good name, and put it to one side. Then, work out how to change the styles for your website - don't think about seasons, just try something easy like "make everything bright red". Then, work out how to make PHP select between two different styles - bright red and dark blue, maybe. And so on - only once you have all the pieces do you put it together to fulfil the original requirement.

Answer (score 0):

hey all so after reading/studying and taking your answers into consideration, I managed to develop a solution so here it is:

````
    // Locate the css for the season
    $seasons = array(
        "spring" => "assets/css/spring.css",
        "summer" => "assets/css/summer.css",
        "autumn" => "assets/css/autumn.css",
        "winter" => "assets/css/winter.css"
    );
    // What is today's date - number
    $day = date("z");
    // Days of spring
    $spring_starts = date("z", strtotime("March 21"));
    $spring_ends = date("z", strtotime("June 20"));
    // Days of summer
    $summer_starts = date("z", strtotime("June 21"));
    $summer_ends = date("z", strtotime("September 22"));
    // Days of autumn
    $autumn_starts = date("z", strtotime("September 23"));
    $autumn_ends = date("z", strtotime("December 20"));
    // If $day is between the days of spring, summer, autumn, and winter
    if ($day >= $spring_starts && $day <= $spring_ends) : $season = "spring";
    elseif ($day >= $summer_starts && $day <= $summer_ends) : $season = "summer";
    elseif ($day >= $autumn_starts && $day <= $autumn_ends) : $season = "autumn";
    else : $season = "winter";
    endif;
    $season_path = $seasons[$season];
    // $season_data = get_season_stylesheet();
    $stylesheet_handle = $season;
    $stylesheet_src = get_theme_file_uri($season_path);
    $deps = false;
    $ver = null;
    $media = 'screen';
    wp_enqueue_style($stylesheet_handle, $stylesheet_src, $deps, $ver, $media);
}
add_action('init', 'load_season_stylesheet');```
````

Comment: Currently (August) it's [winter](http://www.southafrica.org.tr/index.php/south-africa/seasons-and-climate) in South Africa ...

Answer (score -1):

I would use **same** css file for all seasons, only differentiating them by the class you would add to the `body` tag according to the season.

**PHP**

```php
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
 
    $classes[] = $season;   // summer, winter etc using your function
     
    return $classes;
     
}
```

**css**

```css
body.winter {
  background: gray;
}
body.winter h1 {
  color: white;
}
body.summer{
  background: yellow;
}
body.summer h1{
  color: red;
}
```

etc.